# The meaning of “one-closet cell”

Tags: meaning

The passage below comes from The Brooklyn Follies by Paul Auster.

> It [=the studio apartment] was a dingy *one-closet cell* with a metal
>   shower in the bathroom, a pair of windows that looked out on a brick
>   wall, and a pint-sized kitchenette that featured a bar refrigerator
>   and a two-burner gas stove.

I want to know the meaning of the ‘one-closet cell.’
It seems to mean the studio apartment is *a cell the size of a closet*, that is *very small*.
Am I right?

Comment: "Cell" is a reference to a prison cell.  I would interpret "one-closet" to mean that there is a tiny closet in the space somewhere, but that's open to interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

That is incorrect. Think of it as a cell with a closet; in this case, the closet is the bathroom, and the rest of the house -- including the kitchen -- is the cell.